# Ruby on Rails collection_radio_buttons for Star Rating issue with error check

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, rating, collection-radio-buttons

I used some code a while back that I found only for a star rating system (can't seem to locate the tutorial again).  It uses collection_radio_buttons to display the stars while hiding the actual radio button. It works great, but if the user forgets to select a star rating, resulting in an error in the form, the radio buttons become visible when the form gets re-rendered.  I am trying to figure out how to hide the radio button, but can't seem to figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: screenshot]

new.html.erb

```
  <%= form_with(model: @review, url: [@facility, @review]) do |f| %>

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 review-container-border">

  <%= render :partial => 'shared/error_messages', :locals => { :object => @review} %>

  <%= f.label :rating, "Overall Rating" %>
  <div class="rating">
    <%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:rating, [[5],[4],[3],[2],[1]], :first, :last) do |star| %>
      <%= star.radio_button %>
      <%= star.label(class: "text-white") %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

css code:

```
    .rating {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  // height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.rating-0 {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.rating > input {
  display: none;
}

.rating > label {
  font-size:0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: auto;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='126.729' height='126.73'%3e%3cpath fill='%23d3d3d3' d='M121.215 44.212l-34.899-3.3c-2.2-.2-4.101-1.6-5-3.7l-12.5-30.3c-2-5-9.101-5-11.101 0l-12.4 30.3c-.8 2.1-2.8 3.5-5 3.7l-34.9 3.3c-5.2.5-7.3 7-3.4 10.5l26.3 23.1c1.7 1.5 2.4 3.7 1.9 5.9l-7.9 32.399c-1.2 5.101 4.3 9.3 8.9 6.601l29.1-17.101c1.9-1.1 4.2-1.1 6.1 0l29.101 17.101c4.6 2.699 10.1-1.4 8.899-6.601l-7.8-32.399c-.5-2.2.2-4.4 1.9-5.9l26.3-23.1c3.8-3.5 1.6-10-3.6-10.5z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 76%;
  transition: .3s;
}

.rating > input:checked ~ label,
.rating > input:checked ~ label ~ label {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='126.729' height='126.73'%3e%3cpath fill='%23fbbc04' d='M121.215 44.212l-34.899-3.3c-2.2-.2-4.101-1.6-5-3.7l-12.5-30.3c-2-5-9.101-5-11.101 0l-12.4 30.3c-.8 2.1-2.8 3.5-5 3.7l-34.9 3.3c-5.2.5-7.3 7-3.4 10.5l26.3 23.1c1.7 1.5 2.4 3.7 1.9 5.9l-7.9 32.399c-1.2 5.101 4.3 9.3 8.9 6.601l29.1-17.101c1.9-1.1 4.2-1.1 6.1 0l29.101 17.101c4.6 2.699 10.1-1.4 8.899-6.601l-7.8-32.399c-.5-2.2.2-4.4 1.9-5.9l26.3-23.1c3.8-3.5 1.6-10-3.6-10.5z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}


.rating > input:not(:checked) ~ label:hover,
.rating > input:not(:checked) ~ label:hover ~ label {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='126.729' height='126.73'%3e%3cpath fill='%23e0a803' d='M121.215 44.212l-34.899-3.3c-2.2-.2-4.101-1.6-5-3.7l-12.5-30.3c-2-5-9.101-5-11.101 0l-12.4 30.3c-.8 2.1-2.8 3.5-5 3.7l-34.9 3.3c-5.2.5-7.3 7-3.4 10.5l26.3 23.1c1.7 1.5 2.4 3.7 1.9 5.9l-7.9 32.399c-1.2 5.101 4.3 9.3 8.9 6.601l29.1-17.101c1.9-1.1 4.2-1.1 6.1 0l29.101 17.101c4.6 2.699 10.1-1.4 8.899-6.601l-7.8-32.399c-.5-2.2.2-4.4 1.9-5.9l26.3-23.1c3.8-3.5 1.6-10-3.6-10.5z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```

Comment: What do the params sent to backend look like?